# Html.RenderAction with Angular

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, renderaction

I try to write something like below;

```
Html.RenderAction("Reviews", "Poetry", new { id = "{{ poetry.ID }}" });
```

But it gives an error like "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult"

But if i write something like below it works fine;

```
var url = Url.Action("Reviews", "Poetry", new { id = "{{ poetry.ID }}" });
```

How can i pass an angular value in Html.RenderAction method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have controller action like this:

```
public class PoetryController : Controller
{
    public PartialViewResult Reviews(int id)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The `RenderAction` method is parsed and rendered from server before it sent to client's browser, therefore your first approach is **not possible** because Angular expressions like `{{ poetry.ID }}` cannot be parsed properly by server-side code as action parameter, hence it passed as null and throwing non-nullable parameter exception since `id` declared as `int`, not `Nullable<int>`.

Assumed you want to load partial view using Angular value (or JS value), usually  [`$http()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) function is used inside the controller and then call the function name which contains HTTP request:

**JS variable in Razor**

```
var pageUrl = '@Url.Action("Reviews", "Poetry")';
```

**Angular function**

```js
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: pageUrl,
    params: {
        id: poetry.ID
    }).then(function (response) {
        // load partial view here
        angular.element('#targetElement').html(response);
    });
```

Or using shorthanded [`$http.get()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) since `RenderAction` requires GET method to render partial view contents:

```js
$http.get(pageUrl + '?id=' + poetry.ID).then(function (response) {
    // load partial view here
    angular.element('#targetElement').html(response);
});
```